# send json object to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I want to send my json-object wich i got from a api and send i to my controller and parse it to my model.

```
   var playerstats = val.resultSets[4].rowSet[0]
                        $.each(playerstats, function (key, value) {
                            $.ajax({
                                async: false,
                                type: "post",
                                url: "/Stats/addBoxScore",
                                data: JSON.stringify(playerstats),
                                done: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                }
                            });

                        });
```

Here is my controller:

```
  public void addBoxScore(Games playerstats) 
    {
        var gamesID = playerstats;
    }
```

For now im not doing anything in the controller because i can't get the data from the ajaxpost right.

Here is my model:

```
 public class Games
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int GAME_ID { get; set; }
    public int TEAM_ID { get; set; }
    public string TEAM_ABBREVIATION { get; set; }
    public string TEAM_CITY { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PLAYER_ID { get; set; }
    public string PLAYER_NAME { get; set; }
    public string START_POSITION { get; set; }
    public string COMMENT { get; set; }
    public int MIN { get; set; }
    public int FGM { get; set; }
    public int FGA { get; set; }
    public int FG_PCT { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREEM { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREEA { get; set; }
    public int FGTHREE_PCT { get; set; }
    public int FTM { get; set; }
    public int FTA { get; set; }
    public int FT_PCT { get; set; }
    public int OREB { get; set; }
    public int DREB { get; set; }
    public int REB { get; set; }
    public int AST { get; set; }
    public int STL { get; set; }
    public int BLK { get; set; }
    public int TO { get; set; }
    public int PF { get; set; }
    public int PTS { get; set; }
    public int PLUS_MINUS { get; set; }

    public virtual Player player { get; set; } 
}
```

When the data from the ajax post gets to the controller it is all null. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can write the datatype for your sending data and you not need to write the "strngify".

```
datatype: "json"
```

Comment: This doesn't work either:
  $.ajax({
       async: false,
       dataType: "json",
       type: "post",
       url: "/Stats/addBoxScore",
       data: playerstats,
       done: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
      },
       error: function (jqXHR, err) {
     console.log(err);
 }

Comment: I think the problem with wrong json which you send to controller. Check the correct of your json in your backend.

Comment: hmm... Is it realy json? doesn't this row make it to an array? var playerstats = val.resultSets[4].rowSet[0]

Comment: Try send array or other object, for example and check it in backend.

Comment: Try `data: { playerstats: playerstats }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing data as JSON.stringify(...) you are passing a string. I would suggest the following edit to the Action :

```
public void addBoxScore(string playerstats) 
    {
       //Use a deserializing library to convert the string to a strongly typed class.
    }
```

You can use [this library](http://json.codeplex.com/) for deserialization.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i do that playerstats will be null

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to your question, in order for the parameter to map itself to the action argument, you need to specify the name like so :- data: { playerstats: JSON.stringify(playerstats) }